# Problem with static variable initialization C

Tags: c, embedded

I am facing a problem with my static variable which take a random value at the startup of the program and not initialized to `0` as I am expecting it to work.

I have this function in a first
file 1:

```
void setInput()
{
    /*.... Code ...*/
    sysUpdate(SysOutput.u16_state);
    
    /*.... Code ...*/
}
```

which calls the sysUpdate function in another
file 2:

```
bool sysUpdate(uint16 state)
{
    static uint32 u32_Counter = 0;
    
    if (Condition)
    {
        u32_Counter += 30;
        if (u32_Counter > 30000)
        {
            u32_Counter = (uint32)0;
            /*.... Code ...*/
        }
    }

    /*.... Code ...*/
}
```

The problem is that my `u32_Counter` takes a random value despite of initializing it to 0, and my condition is always true the first time.

Do you have any idea on the reason of this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Update :
This problem was caused by a writing out of the boundries of another static array. This is what exactly caused the problem :

```
static uint8 state[xNUMBER][yNUMBER]; 
const uint8 state1[xNUMBER][yNUMBER] = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0},{1, 1, 1, 1}}; 
const uint8 state2[xNUMBER][yNUMBER] = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0},{1, 1, 1, 1}}; 
length = sizeof(state)/sizeof(state[0][0]);
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            state[i][j] = state1[i][j];
        }
        else           
        {
            state[i][j] = state2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using class, it C not C++. or you mean function? I tried using it as global static variable but the same problem

Comment: We can't help on why the condition behaves as it does because you've not shown us what it is.  The random value could be caused by writing outside of the boundaries of another array.

Comment: The condition is just to test on a flag triggred by a button which doesn't have any link to the u32_counter.

Comment: static variables do work unless your toolchain is buggy. please provide a [mre]

Comment: Okay i'll try to update my question to make it reproducible, thanks

Comment: add logging of value on each call and I bet the first call is 0

Comment: I did that and the first time i go into the function the counter take a random value which make the condition ````if(u32_Counter > 30000)`````True and the line '''u32_Counter = (uint32)0;''' is executed.
After that no problem everything works fine, only that first time where i have the problem.

Comment: As  Jonathan Leffler said this may be caused by writing outside of the boundaries of another array. because the problems occures when i added this : 
static uint8 state[xNUMBER][yNUMBER];
const uint8 state1[xNUMBER][yNUMBER] = {{FALSE, TRUE , FALSE, FALSE},
{TRUE , TRUE , FALSE, FALSE},{FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE }};
const uint8 state2[xNUMBER][yNUMBER] = {{FALSE, TRUE , TRUE , TRUE },
{TRUE , FALSE, TRUE , TRUE },{FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE}};
and i initialize the state with state1 or state2 based on the state of a button.

Comment: As others have said, it sounds like the memory is getting corrupted somehow.  Try compiling with the address sanitizer enabled: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

Comment: @SmallX "my condition is always true the first time." --> how did you determine it was the _first_?

Comment: Reinstate Monica, because this function is called when i press a button... So when i press it the first time the counter take a random value greater than the 3000 in my condition.
And once i press the button again everything work as expected as the counter was initialized through this line u32_Counter = (uint32)0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your environment is seriously broken, the initial value of `u32_Counter` is guaranteed to be `0`.

A likely explanation is this global variable is overwritten by code executed before the test that shows the problem.

You can try and investigate by looking at the map file or list of symbols and their addresses (using the `nm` or `objdump` utilities) to see what variable or array is laid out just before `u32_Counter`.  A buffer overrun may cause what you observe.

You could move the definition outside the function so you can print the value of `u32_Counter` at different times during the execution of the initial code.  Yet the problem might disappear if you do this as the variable may be laid out at a different place in the data segment, thus no longer overwritten, but some other variable may be overwritten then and the side effects may move somewhere else.  Even just removing the `= 0` initializer may have this effect.

If you have a debugger with watch capabilities, set a watch point on this variable to track where and how it gets modified.

Comment: Okay, i'll try to figure out when it's value changes through the debugger and come back here to give a feedback on what i noticed. Thank you

Comment: @chqrilie Thanks for the help i was able to solve the problem by analizing the map file and doing some debugging. This was caused by writing outside of the boundaries of another array. and this is what caused the problem  :
static uint8 state[xNUMBER][yNUMBER];
 const uint8 state1[xNUMBER][yNUMBER] = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 1}};
 const uint8 state2[xNUMBER][yNUMBER] = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}};
length = sizeof(state)/sizeof(state[0][0]);
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){for (j = 0; j < length; j++) { if(condition){ state[i][j] = state1[i][j];}......